Display all movies
i just started learning react and was watching a tutorial but when you load the page the search is set to "Batman" i want when i load the page to get all movies

import MovieCard from "./MovieCard";
import SearchIcon from "./search.svg";
import "./App.css";

const API_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com?apikey=b6003d8a";

const App = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchMovies("Batman");
  }, []);

  const searchMovies = async (title) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    setMovies(data.Search);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>MovieLand</h1>

      <div className="search">
        <input
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Search for movies"
        />
        <img
          src={SearchIcon}
          alt="search"
          onClick={() => searchMovies(searchTerm)}
        />
      </div>

      {movies?.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="container">
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <MovieCard movie={movie} />
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="empty">
          <h2>No movies found</h2>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

this is the code
i tryed to add an if statement to only show not null movies but it didn't work

So, there are some logic issues here. First of all, the best way to fetch data in react is doing that inside the use effect, and the dependencies of the use effect need to be the state, so you can update the state with a fetch when page is load. This is an example:
const [data, setData] = useState([])

UseEffect(()=>{
 Fetch(“https://yourapihere.com/apo”).then(res => res.json()).then(res => setData(res))
}, [data])

So if you do this, after the load of the page you will get the result right!

Thanks for the reply. I tryed your method but it didn't work(or i didn't use it properly). I then asked chat-gpt and it gave me this solution:
useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

  const fetchMovies = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=movie`);
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.Search) {
        setMovies(data.Search);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching movies:", error);
    }
  };

